# Sending data upon redirect to other site

Tags: php, session

I am working in magento. I am redirecting to another website by button click. As magento uses its own session and checks for site id or something so that not to share session data with some other site. So, if i want to share data from a site that maintains its session like that, what can be the suitable way for that?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to incorporate the session id (or the data itself) into the url (kinda unsafe) or to make a cookie that is valid over multiple domains. You can lower the risk of session hijacking by encoding the session id and checking the requesters ip, still a small risk remains when using non-ssl connections.